# Do there exist two functions $f\in C^1_b(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $fg\not\in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2)?$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $C^1_b(\mathbb{R})$ be a collection of all bounded continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with continuous and bounded first derivative.

Let $C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2)$ be a collection of all bounded $\mathbb{R}^2$-valued continuous

> *Question*: Do there exist two functions $f\in C^1_b(\mathbb{R})$ and $g\in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2)$ such that $fg\not\in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2)?$

In other words, is it true that pointwise product between bounded real-valued function and bounded multi-valued function is a bounded multi-valued continuous function?

Continuity is not a problem. 
Clearly if $f$ is a constant function, then $fg\in C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}).$ 
But other than this, I do not know of other examples.

Comment: *Do* there exist two...

Comment: @mathworker21 pardon my lousy English.

Comment: I'm confused. Can't you bound $fg$ by the product of the bounds on $f$ and $g$?

Comment: $||fg||=|f|||g||$ which is bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \in  C_b(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$.

By $||\cdot||$ we denote the euclidic norm on $ \mathbb R^2$.

If $|f(t)| \le c_1$ and $||g(t)|| \le c_2$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.

then $||f(t)g(t)|| \le c_1c_2$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$.